# TP-Link TL-ER6120 Load Balancer: Intermittent Ping Timeout Issue

Tags: networking, router, ping

I am encountering a perplexing issue with my TP-Link TL-ER6120 load balancer, and I'm hoping someone here might be able to provide some insights or solutions. After approximately 15 to 20 minutes of normal operation, I am experiencing ping timeouts when trying to reach the load balancer's IP address (192.168.1.254).

This problem has been consistent, and I've been trying to troubleshoot it on my own, but I'm running out of ideas. Here are some additional details about the setup:

Load Balancer Model: TP-Link TL-ER6120
Load Balancer IP (LAN): 192.168.1.254
Gateway IP: 192.168.1.254
Subnet: 255.255.254.0